# Subseting dataframe (long format) based on another dataframe (wide format) in which cases are repeated

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, longitudinal

I randomly sampled 100 rows from my dataframe (containing 20 rows) in wide format. I used this r code:

```
random_100 <- df.wide[sample(nrow(df.wide), 100, replace = T),]
```

It returns a dataframe containing 100 rows (each with patient-id, treatment-outcome, therapeutic alliance) in which a patient-id might be repeated. Which is great, because that's what i wanted.

As i'm interested in longitudinal effects, i now need to extract the corresponding rows (based on patient-id) from my long format dataframe.
I tried the following code:

```
random_long <- subset(df.long, (df.long$id %in% random_100$id))
```

However, i don't receive 100 patients (*treatment lenght) but only 20 patients.

What code do i need to use to allow a patient to be drawn from the long format dataframe as often as it was randomly selected from my wide format dataframe?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Because there are repeats for the same id?

Comment: Yes, there are repeats for the same id.

Comment: that explains why you got only 20  ids.

Comment: You'll probably have to join/merge in order to get the corresponding info for an id, even if it is repeated.

Comment: yeah, but how can i draw ids multiple times (as often as selected in random sampling)?

Comment: This should help: `dt = data.frame(id = 1:3,
                v = 11:13);

x = c(1,1,2,3,3);

subset(dt, id %in% x);

merge(data.frame(id = x), dt, by.x = "id");`

Comment: my actual data set is quite a but larger, with 1000 random samples which i need to repeat about 300 times. In the end i'll have to create a loop. So manually adding the number of repetitions is not going to work...

Comment: This was an example to show you the difference between using `%in%` and `merge`. This might work for your example `merge(data.frame(id = random_100$id), df.long, by.x = "id")`. Can't help you more without data that represent your actual case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just in way over my head^^

Comment: the wide format data set contains 528 cases with 942 variables. the corresponding long format data set contains 58164 rows with 282 variables. i want to draw 1000 random samples from the wide format data set 264 times. I need to do this to contrast it with non random predictions i already did. The 528 cases are in my training data set and the 264 times repetition is based on the number of cases in my test set (cross validation).

Comment: The 1000 randomly sampled cases (in long format) are subsequently entered in an OLS-Regression loop and the median slope of these 1000 cases is extracted to predict the slopes from my test data set. Hope this makes it a little clearer..

Comment: You'll get better help, faster, if you can provide a [mcve].  You don't need to provide your actual data, but it should be toy data that is representative, at least in structure, of your actual data, and which demonstrates the issue you're running into (plus your expected output).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant solution, but this might give you the result you want

```
#make up some data
df.wide <- data.frame(id = 1:20, V1 = letters[1:20])

df.long <- data.frame(id = rep(1:20, 50), V2 = paste0("t", 1:1000))

#pull 100 random sampeles
set.seed(3)

random_100 <- df.wide[sample(nrow(df.wide), 100, replace = T),]

#count how many random samples were selected for each patient
x1 <- table(random_100$id)

#pull the corresponding number from df.long
a1 <- lapply(seq_along(x1), function(i) {
  y <- df.long[df.long$id == names(x1)[[i]],]  
  y1 <- y[sample(row.names(y), x1[[i]], replace = T),]
})

#combine
res <- do.call("rbind", a1)
```